# check how do i delete a specific element from a numpy matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

For example, I have a numpy array:

```
game.mat = np.zeros((6,7))
```

How can I remove the element for example, say in row 0 and column 5 of the matrix?

Is it possible to use the `np.delete()` function?

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove one cell of a matrix.  A matrix (both in mathematics and in NumPy) is a rectangular "table" of numbers, and it does not have gaps.

What you can do is mark the value as missing or unusable.  Two common ways to do that are:

1. Replace the value with `np.nan` (or some known value like 0 or -1 if the dtype is integer, hence lacks NAN support).
2. Use [numpy.ma](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/maskedarray.generic.html), the "masked array" module which carries a boolean array (matrix) alongside your regular data, indicating which values are usable and which are not.